# how to handle invalid index id error in netezza while using array_split?

Tags: sql, netezza

```
SELECT T1.AC_NO FROM TALE1 T1  
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2  
ON T1.AC_NO=  
CASE  
   WHEN T2.COMMON_KEY LIKE '%~%' AND T2.COMMON_KEY IS NOT NULL 
      THEN   GET_VALUE_VARCHAR(ARRAY_SPLIT(T2.COMMON_KEY,'~'),2)  
   ELSE T2.COMMON_KEY  
END
```

DATA IN TABLE1:

```
AC_NO  
1  
2  
3  
4
```

DATA IN TABLE2

```
COMMON_KEY  

A~1~EF  
B~2~CD  
3  
4
```

ABOVE QUERY THROWS AN ERROR OF :

> ERROR [HY000] ERROR: 0 : Invalid Index Id

Comment: Could you please clarify both the scenario, and what you are trying to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: compare the values in columns of both tables and fetch the data that matches my requirement.Second table contains a column with same data of first table but additionally few variables are appended to make data unique (i.e A~1~EF).

Answer (score 2):

Scott is onto something here- just make sure it never fails. My suggestion would be to concatenate an extra '~' at the end of the string inside the case:

```
SELECT T1.AC_NO 
FROM TABLE 1T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T1.AC_NO=
CASE
   WHEN T2.COMMON_KEY LIKE '%~%' AND T2.COMMON_KEY IS NOT NULL
      THEN   GET_VALUE_VARCHAR(ARRAY_SPLIT(T2.COMMON_KEY||'~','~'),2))
   ELSE T2.COMMON_KEY
END;
```

A matter of preference, but I find it more readable :)

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason Netezza evaluates the THEN expression of a case involving UDFs (which the array fucntions from the SQL Extention Toolkit you are using happen to be) whether the WHERE expression is true or not.

What is happening here is that because of this behavior, it tries to pull the 2nd element from arrays with only one element, giving you  the "Invalid Index ID" error when it tries to execute GET_VALUE_VARCHAR(...,2) on the arrays with only 1 value (e.g. 3 and 4), even though you'd think the CASE should never need to test that.

A workaround can be made by making the THEN expression not fail, regardless.

```
SELECT T1.AC_NO 
FROM TABLE 1T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T1.AC_NO=
CASE
   WHEN T2.COMMON_KEY LIKE '%~%' AND T2.COMMON_KEY IS NOT NULL
      THEN   GET_VALUE_VARCHAR(ARRAY_SPLIT(T2.COMMON_KEY,'~'),min(array_count(ARRAY_SPLIT(T2.COMMON_KEY,'~')),2))
   ELSE T2.COMMON_KEY
END;
```

Comment: Netezza is not doing "lazy evaluation"